# Get HTML content from onion links using the request library (Python 3)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get the html code of onion websites using the requests library (or urllib.request). I tried diverse methods but none of them seemed to work properly.

At first, I simply tried to connect to a proxy using the requests library and get the HTML code of the facebook deep web:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
session.proxie = {}
session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'

r = requests.get('https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/')

print(r.text)
```

However, when I do this, the connection to the proxy doesn't work (my IP stays the same with or without the proxy).

I get the following error:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='facebookcorewwwi.onion', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x109e8b198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

After doing some research, I saw someone who tried to do a similar thing and the solution was to connect to the proxy before importing the `requests`/`urllib.request` library.

So I tried connecting using the libraries `socks` and `socket`:

```
import socks
import socket

def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

# patch the socket module
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection



import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/') as response:
    html = response.read()
    print(html)
```

When I do this, my connection the the proxy gets refused:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 127.0.0.1:9050: [Errno 61] Connection refused>
```

I tried to use the `requests` library instead like follow (simply replace it from the line that says `import urllib.request`)

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/')
print(r.text)
```

But here I get this error:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='facebookcorewwwi.onion', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10d93ee80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

It seem that no matter what I do my connection to a proxy gets refused. Does anyone have an alternative solution or a way to fix this?

Comment: In your initial code snippet, you never actually make a request with your session. Change `requests.get('https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/')` to `session.get(url)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did indeed try this and got the following response `raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='facebookcorewwwi.onion', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x10634dbe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))` For some reason, the connection is always refused no matter what.

Comment: it works for me; my tor socks proxy lives on port 9150 rather than the one you said.  I get the same error when I use an invalid proxy port